# Fetch 100 rows at a time using RowHandler in IBatis(Oracle 11g database ) - Example

Tags: oracle11g, ibatis

I need to fetch 2 million records from the oracle database(1 year data).
When I am retrieving it as list, it is taking 'n' minutes and it hangs.

```
sqlMap.queryForList("getResultSet", parameterMap);
```

So, I tried implementing IBatis `"RowHandler"` interface and I overrided the `"handleRow(Object obj)"` and I am able to get the result (One row at a time).

But I need to get 'n' rows at a time where n >= 1000. So I added `fetchSize="1000" and resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY"` attribute to my select statement.

E.g:

```
<select id='getResultSet' parameterClass='java.util.Map' fetchSize="1000" resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY">
```

But still I am getting only one row at a time in the `"handleRow(Object obj)"` method.

```java
@Override
public void handleRow(Object queryResult) {     

        if(queryResult != null) {

            try {

                tempResultMap = (ClassName) queryResult;
                resultList.add(tempResultMap);
                System.out.println("List Size -> " + reportList.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }   
    }
```

When the method is called during query execution, `"List Size ->"` is always incrementing by one. But I am expecting increment rate of 1000 (As I have given fetchSize = "1000")...

When I googled out, there is a property available(`Driver.useCursorFetch`) which can be used along with `"fetchSize" and "resultSetType"`.
Reference : http://www.yaldex.com/mysql_manual/ch23s04.html or [Ibatis queryWithRowHandler() still seems to fetch all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870500/ibatis-querywithrowhandler-still-seems-to-fetch-all-rows).
But I think it is only for MySQL Database.
What is the equivalent property(`Driver.useCursorFetch`) for Oracle 11g database.
I need some configuration like below.

```
<bean id="sourceName" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />                         
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid" />
    <property name="username" value="$uname" />
    <property name="password" value="$pwd" />
    <!-- 
    Some thing like this 
    <property name="configName(Instead of Driver.useCursorFetch)" value="true/false" />
    -->

</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleRow` only gives you a single row. Using `fetchSize`, you should be able to delete your `handleRow` method, if I understand your scenario correctly.

If you really do need to handle each rown individually, you can make a stateful (non-singleton) RowHandler with a private list and implements the Observer pattern, notifying listeners each time you've hit 1000 records.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.. What I am exactly trying to do is "Consider I already have 10 million records in my database from which I have to pull 1 million records(Say 1 year data). Instead of fetching 1 million records at a time from the database, I am trying to fetch some thousands of records at a time and keep fetching it until I fetch all the 1 million records using "fetchSize" option. But it is(fetchSize) fetching one record at a time(instead of 1000 records) until all the 1 million record is fetched". Any suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: You `new` up a custom row handler that has a `List` of row objects and a counter. Before passing the rowhandler into iBATIS, set up your observers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Then, in `handleRow`, `counter++` and `list.add(row)`. Once the counter hits 1000, notify observers, sending them the list and clear the list.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Will try it out.